# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional

Tags: swift, ios8, option-type

```
@IBOutlet weak var groupNameTF: UITextField!
var group: Group? {
    didSet {
        groupNameTF.text = group?.name
    }
}
```

Can't understand what the problem with optional here. As I see from logs, `group` isn't `nil`. As I thought I do safe value unwrapping. I also checked with `if let` construction, same result.

Comment: Is maybe `groupNameTF` nil?

Comment: @Antonio yes, you're absolutely right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely that happens because `groupNameTF` is nil. A quick workaround is to protect that with an if:

```
var group: Group? {
    didSet {
        if groupNameTF != nil {
            groupNameTF.text = group?.name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I think, in this case it should fail hard. `groupNameTF` is an outlet. The main reason why it might be `nil` is you forgot to connect it in interface builder.

Comment: @JeremyP another option is that outlets have not been connected yet - it can happen when you create the view (or view controller) by code, and right after you set that property. Outlets will be bound at a later stage in the view lifecycle.

Answer (score 4):

@Antonio already explained the problem. An alternative solution is

```
var group: Group? {
    didSet {
        groupNameTF?.text = group?.name
    }
}
```

using optional chaining on the left-hand side of the expression. If `groupNameTF` 
is `nil` then the `text` setter method will not be called.

Comment: +1 nice thinking. Proof that things in swift can be done in several ways, which is always good

Comment: @Antonio: So Swift is the new Perl :-) TIMTOWTDI!

Comment: ahah yeah we should rename it to Swifterl :).