# Concatenate values returned from an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, concatenation

I'm training on Swift, doing some exercises with arrays. I would like to pick up randomly 6 letters in an array containing the 26 letters of the alphabet, then concatenate them to generate a string.

I have no problem picking the values, but when it comes to concatenate them, I get error messages.

Here is my code :

```
var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

var a = alphabet.randomElement()
var b = alphabet.randomElement()
var c = alphabet.randomElement()
var d = alphabet.randomElement()
var e = alphabet.randomElement()
var f = alphabet.randomElement()

var password = a + b + c + d + e + f

print(password)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the error? DId you try printing `var a`, what is the output?

Comment: Is `alphabet` intentionally an `Array<String>` rather than an `Array<Character>`?

Comment: I nominated the question for re-opening because the linked question this is supposed to be a duplicate of was actually about a different problem, although the overall task in which it occurred was the same

Answer (score 4):

Your alphabet is currently an `[String]` (a.k.a. `Array<String>`). You should probably change it to an `[Character]` instead.

Even better, since `randomElement` is defined on `Collection`, and `Collection` whose `Element` is `Character` would work. `String` is a `Collection`, and its `Element` is `Character`, so it fits the bill perfectly. The nicest way to do that is by breaking apart a string literal:

```
let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

`randomElement()` returns a `T?` (in this case, `String?`, a.k.a. `Optional<String>`), not just a `T`. Because if `alphabet` were to be empty (it's not, but if it was), then there would be no elements to return. The only sane thing to do is return `nil` instead.

Since in your case you can be certain that `alphabet` is non-empty, and that `randomElement()` will always return a valid non element, you're justified to force unwrap the result with the `!` operator. *Now don't make a bad habit of this.* You have good reason to force unwrap here, but it's not to be used as a first-resort method of optional handling.

You're also repeating yourself a lot. You can improve this by using a loop of some kind or another.

In this case, you can use a neat little trick. Starting with a range like `0..<6`, which has 6 elements, you can call `map` on it to transform its elements (which are `0`, `1`, ... `5`). In this case, you woudl transform each element by ignoring it, and just replacing it with a random element frmo the alphabet:

```
(0..<6).map { _ in alphabet.randomElement()! }
```

The result is an `Array<Character>`. All you need is to turn it into a string. Final code:

```
let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
let password = String((0..<6).map { _ in alphabet.randomElement()! })
```

Comment: Just note that OP's `alphabet` is an array of strings, not of characters.So you probably need to join them.

Comment: @MartinR `flatMap` does the trick: `String((0 ..< 6).flatMap { _ in alphabet.randomElement()! })`

Comment: @JeremyP Or `(0 ..< 6).map { _ in alphabet.randomElement()! }.joined()`. [As I said before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860829/unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional/26861120#comment42282987_26861120): “Swift is the new Perl – TIMTOWTDI!”

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I think you need to change your first paragraph because, you don't get a `Character?` in this case, you get a `String?`.

Comment: @MartinR I like: `let a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ; let r = String((0 ..< 6).compactMap { _ in a.randomElement() })`

Comment: @JeremyP I would rather check if OP to see that they really meant to have a `[String]` instead of `[Character]`

Comment: @LeoDabus: Jeremy edited his comment, my response does not apply  anymore (I have deleted it now).

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica You could recommend he change the declaration of `alphabet` but the assumption must currently be he means an array of strings. I'm only asking you to change it because your answer is otherwise the best and I want to upvote it, but I can't with the factual error in the first line.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Great. I took the liberty of editing a missed occurrence  of `Character` but also upvoted. Also, in the circumstances, you don't need to convert the string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" to an array because you can apply `.randomElement()` directly to a string.

Answer (score 1):

`a, b, c, d, e, f` are of type `String?`. So you need to **unwrap** them either using `if-let` or *force-unwrapping* before, i.e.

Using **force-unwrapping**,

```
let a = alphabet.randomElement()!
let b = alphabet.randomElement()!
let c = alphabet.randomElement()!
let d = alphabet.randomElement()!
let e = alphabet.randomElement()!
let f = alphabet.randomElement()!
```

Using **`if-let`**,

```
if let a = alphabet.randomElement(), let b = alphabet.randomElement(), let c = alphabet.randomElement(), let d = alphabet.randomElement(), let e = alphabet.randomElement(), let f = alphabet.randomElement() {
    let password = a + b + c + d + e + f
    print(password)
}
```

Using *if-let* is safer than *force-unwrapping*.

**Note:** Use `let` instead of `var` when using constant values.

Comment: Thank you very much,, it works !!! But I would like to understand why, what is the rule with "!" character ? When do you need to put one ?

Comment: @SamAm You should read up on Optional, an important concept in swift

Comment: @SamAm https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, guys

Comment: @SamAm Concatenation operation deals with non-optional values. So, you need to unwrap any optional values before using `+` operation. For unwrapping you either using `!` or `if-let` statement. Do read more about optionals.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think the simplest solution is to declare an extension at the top level of your file, allowing you to concatenate Optional Strings coherently:

```
func +(lhs:String?, rhs:String?) -> String {
    return (lhs ?? "") + (rhs ?? "")
}
```

Now your original code will compile and run correctly without changes (except that I changed `var` to `let` everywhere to eliminate compiler warnings):

```
let alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

let a = alphabet.randomElement()
let b = alphabet.randomElement()
let c = alphabet.randomElement()
let d = alphabet.randomElement()
let e = alphabet.randomElement()
let f = alphabet.randomElement()

let password = a + b + c + d + e + f

print(password) // cpndmz
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this method

```
func randomPassword(digit : Int) -> String {
    var password = ""
    for _ in 0 ..< digit {
        let number = Int.random(in: 97...122)
        password += "\(UnicodeScalar(number)!)"
    }
    return  password.uppercased()
}

let password = randomPassword(digit: 6)
print(password)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but far too complicated for me at the moment ^^

Answer (score 1):

As others already mentioned, randomElement() can return nil as the reference says:

An easy solution will be like the following.

```
let password = alphabet[Int.random(in: 0...25)]
              + alphabet[Int.random(in: 0...25)]
              + alphabet[Int.random(in: 0...25)]
              + alphabet[Int.random(in: 0...25)]
              + alphabet[Int.random(in: 0...25)]
              + alphabet[Int.random(in: 0...25)]
```

In this way, basically you tell swift that you want to handle the array out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating all these `a, b, c, d, e, f` variables, you can simply use **`reduce(_:_:)`** to get the expected result.

```
let password = (1...6).reduce("") { (result, _) -> String in
    return result + (alphabet.randomElement() ?? "")
}
```

Comment: This is nice but I just can't condone teaching a beginner to use `!`. I suggest `result + (alphabet.randomElement() ?? "")` as in my answer.

Comment: @matt Updated that. Thanks.

Comment: The only case where `randomElement()` returns `nil` is for an *empty* collection. If the alphabet is a non-empty array (known at compile time) then I do not see a problem in force-unwrapping.